# Cannot retrieve id of selected row using button in each row of mat-table of angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, frontend, single-page-application

I have mat-table component from angular material. I populate it and i want to retrieve id of selected row. In each row I placed a button with which i want get that id. Below i put image of it [image of mat-table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVQ0X.png). In column "Id" I print real Id values which I want to retrieve. Maybe Somebody occured the same problem.

AVAILABLE-COURSES.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { CourseService } from 'src/app/_services/course.service';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/_services/auth.service';
import { MatPaginator, MatSort, MatTableDataSource } from         '@angular/material';
import { courseEnrolments } from 'src/app/_models/courseEnrolments';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-available-courses',
   templateUrl: './available-courses.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./available-courses.component.scss']
 })
  export class AvailableCoursesComponent implements OnInit {
   dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
    courseEnrolments: courseEnrolments[];
   displayedColumns = [
    'id',
    'name',
    'description',
    'other',
    'checked',
   ];
   @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
   @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

   constructor(
   private courseService: CourseService,
   private authService: AuthService
   ) {}

   ngOnInit() {
   this.courseService
  .getAllCourses()
  .subscribe(result => {

    if (!result) {
      return;
    }

    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(result);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
   });
   }
   applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim();
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase();
     this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
   }
  handleClick(event: Event) {
   console.log('‘Click’', event);
  }
}
```

AVAILABLE-COURSES.HTML`

```
 </div>
 <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="courses">
 <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
 <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Id </mat-header-cell>
 <mat-cell *matCellDef="let courseEnrolments"> {{courseEnrolments.id}} </mat-   cell>
</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="name">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Course Name </mat-header-cell>
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let courseEnrolments"> {{courseEnrolments.name}}        </mat-cell>
 </ng-container>
 <ng-container matColumnDef="description">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Description </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let courseEnrolments">    {{    courseEnrolments.description}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="other">
 <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Other informations </mat-header-cell>
 <mat-cell *matCellDef="let courseEnrolments"> {{courseEnrolments.other}}  </mat-cell>
 </ng-container>
 <ng-container matColumnDef="checked">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Enlist</mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let courseEnrolments">
    <button  (click)="handleClick($event)"_ngcontent-c54="" color="primary"    mat-stroked-button="" class="mat-stroked-button mat-primary"><span
      class="mat-button-wrapper">Enlist</span>
     <div class="mat-button-ripple mat-ripple" matripple=""></div>
     <div class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></div>
   </button>
  </mat-cell>

</ng-container>
<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
 <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve id in the following way:

```
 <button  (click)="handleClick(courseEnrolments.id)"_ngcontent-c54="" color="primary"    mat-stroked-button="" class="mat-stroked-button mat-primary"><span
  class="mat-button-wrapper">Enlist</span>
  <div class="mat-button-ripple mat-ripple" matripple=""></div>
  <div class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></div>
</button>
```

Comment: print undefined

Comment: handleClick(id) {
    console.log(id);
  }
}

Comment: but you should pass the whole object  - not only id. Can you provide some example on stackblitz ?

Comment: I dont understand

Comment: must I somethiong do in ts. file?

Comment: Please write in English. I think it will be enough to replace the code what I provided with yours one. What I meant is that you got the access to  'id' only through 'courseEnrolments' object. So you need to pass it to click event callback which in our case is handleClick(course Enrolments.id).

Answer (score 0):

you can below example code:

```
 <tr mat-row (click)="selectRow(mytemplate, row)" *matRowDef="let row; columns: 
  displayedColumns;"></tr>
```

For more info please check : [get row id on row click angular](https://therichpost.com/open-modal-popup-with-dynamic-data-on-click-event-angular-material-datatable-row)

Comment: can u pls tell me how to pass selected row values to click event. am having button above mat-table. i just want pass the selected value to that button. based on that am trying to do routing.

Comment: Okay I will tell you.

Comment: @worstCoder did you check my above link?